# What platform do I need? Wiki, Tiki, or something else

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use)

I need to set up a collaborative website, like a wiki but where the items have a predefined structure.

For example, a collaborative recipe website where a submission would consist of a photo, ingredients, instructions, cooking time, etc...
Is there any any open source platforms out there that allow collaborative editing with structured entities?

Many thanks!

Comment: Belongs on Webmasters SE.

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal](http://www.drupal.org/).

Comment: Worth noting that if you are using Drupal 6, this answer should really be Drupal + CCK (the content creation kit, which allows you to define custom fields). Drupal 7 has this built in, but has only just come out, so you may want to stick with 6 for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UserRights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights) to prevent users with basic account roles from adding new pages if you opt for [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) - skinning MediaWiki is fairly easy and users don't need to know HTML to update content, so all in all it could work as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress? http://buddypress.org/

Answer (score 0):

We use MediaWiki together with the [MultiBoilerplate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiBoilerplate) extension which means users can select from multiple default pages using a drop down list. It is also very easy to configure the default pages and add / remove boilerplates.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) solution, and maybe, using bitnami [installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/mediawiki) to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Tiki](http://tiki.org) by using Trackers and Wiki pages.